# javascript - dry - how to nest

Tags: javascript, dry

I am new to coding, but have been reading about DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) code.

I have a JavaScript if/else statement that does not fit the DRY approach, but I am unable to workout how to write it so that the statements are not repeated.

I am hoping someone smarter than me can show me.

Here is my code:

```
if (response.weather[0].description == "clear sky") {
    const v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
    v1.setAttribute("src", "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4");
    v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")
    document.body.appendChild(v1)
    v1.autoplay = true;
    v1.load();
} else if (response.weather[0].description == "few clouds") {
    v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
    v1.setAttribute("src", "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4");
    v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")
    document.body.appendChild(v1)
    v1.autoplay = true;
    v1.load();
}
```

Comment: do you have other `descriptions` than above?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `urls` configuration for your URLs to eliminate the use of if/else statements altogether, as well as a `loadVideo` function to avoid code repetition.

Here's the solution:

```
// configure your URLs by weather (using the weather description in this case)
const urls = {
    'clear sky': 'https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4',
    'few clouds': 'https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4'
};

// function that loads the video based on a URL
function loadVideo(url) {
    const v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
    v1.setAttribute('src', url);
    v1.setAttribute('class', 'v1');
    document.body.appendChild(v1);
    v1.autoplay = true;
    v1.load();
}

// call the function with the response from your API
loadVideo(urls[response.weather[0].description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract common parts outside the if statement:

```
let v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")

if (response.weather[0].description == "clear sky") {
    v1.setAttribute("src", "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4");
} else if (response.weather[0].description == "few clouds") {
    v1.setAttribute("src", "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4");
}
document.body.appendChild(v1)
v1.autoplay = true;
v1.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Factor your code out into a separate function.

```
function addVideo(url) {
    const v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
    v1.setAttribute("src", url);
    v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")
    document.body.appendChild(v1)
    v1.autoplay = true;
    v1.load();
}

switch (response.weather[0].description) {
    case "clear sky": 
        addVideo("https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4");
        break;
    case "few clouds": 
        addVideo("https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4");
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a plain object to map description values to URLs, and eliminate the `switch`. This is especially preferable if you have several videos since this would be even DRYer than the first approach.

```
function addVideo(url) {
    const v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
    v1.setAttribute("src", url);
    v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")
    document.body.appendChild(v1)
    v1.autoplay = true;
    v1.load();
}

var descriptionVideoMapping = {
    "clear sky": "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4",
    "few clouds": "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4",
};

var url = descriptionVideoMapping[response.weather[0].description];

if (url) {
    addVideo(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do just use a ternary operator if you have only 2 conditions to check. And if you have more then 2 checks you can use switch.

```
const { description } = response.weather[0];

const clearSkyUrl =
  "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4";

const cloudSkyUrl =
  "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4";

const v1 = document.createElement("VIDEO");
v1.setAttribute("src", description === "clear sky" ? clearSkyUrl : cloudSkyUrl);
v1.setAttribute("class", "v1");
document.body.appendChild(v1);
v1.autoplay = true;
v1.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the links into an object with `descritption` as key and check if the description exists and create a new object with the wanted link.

```
var description = response.weather[0].description,
    links = {
        VIDEO: "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4",
        "few clouds": "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/501/original/cloudysky.mp4"
    };

if (description in links) {
    const v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
    v1.setAttribute("src", links[description]);
    v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")
    document.body.appendChild(v1)
    v1.autoplay = true;
    v1.load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My improve code

```
if (['clear sky', 'few clouds'].includes(response.weather[0].description)) {
  const v1 = document.createElement('VIDEO');
  const srcVideo = response.weather[0].description == 'clear sky' ? 
  'https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4' : 'https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/011/710/original/Clouds_Timelapse_21_-_60s_-_4k_res.mp4'
  v1.setAttribute("src", srcVideo);
  v1.setAttribute("class", "v1")
  document.body.appendChild(v1)
  v1.autoplay = true;
  v1.load();
}
```